# unable to mount NFS with specific permissions

Tags: mount, nfs

I have an NFS Drive which I an using for `owncloud`, now I have mounted the NFS drive using mount command like this:

```
mount -t nfs 172.16.2.x:/shares/OwnCloud /eStore/
```

But `owncloud` complaint about extra permission to the `/eStore` directory which is `777` by default and is the data directory for `owncloud`

```
drwxrwxrwx   10 root root  4096 Jan  4 12:42 eStore
```

To overcome this issue I used the following:

```
mount -t nfs -o umask=0007,gid=65534,uid=65534
172.16.2.x:/shares/OwnCloud /eStore/
```

Where `65534` is `nfsnobody` user which is used by `nfs` and mask `0007` which is equal to `0770`.

Now the problem is that this mount command is not working and I am getting the following error:

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```